# Why does the shape of the selection of my pandas dataframe is wrong

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, shapes

I have a pandas DataFrame called `df` where `df.shape` is `(53, 80)` where indexes and columns are both `int`.

If I select the first row like this, I get :

```
df.loc[0].shape
(80,)
```

instead of :

```
(1,80)
```

But then `df.loc[0:0].shape` or `df[0:1].shape` both show the correct shape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`df.loc[0]` returns a **one-dimensional** `pd.Series` object representing the data in a single row, extracted via indexing.

`df.loc[0:0]` returns a **two-dimensional** `pd.DataFrame` object representing the data in a dataframe with one row, extracted via slicing.

You can see this more clearly if you print the results of these operations:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3))

res1 = df.loc[0]
res2 = df.loc[0:0]

print(type(res1), res1, sep='\n')

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    0
1    1
2    2
Name: 0, dtype: int32

print(type(res2), res2, sep='\n')

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
   0  1  2
0  0  1  2
```

The convention follows NumPy indexing / slicing. This is natural since Pandas is built on NumPy arrays.

```
arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)

print(arr[0].shape)    # (3,), i.e. 1-dimensional
print(arr[0:0].shape)  # (0, 3), i.e. 2-dimensional
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call `df.iloc[0]`, it is selecting first row and type is `Series` whereas, in other case `df.iloc[0:0]` it is slicing rows and is of type `dataframe`. And `Series` are according to [pandas Series documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) :

> One-dimensional ndarray with axis labels

whereas `dataframe` are **Two-dimensional** ([pandas Dataframe documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)).

Try running following lines to see the difference:

```
print(type(df.iloc[0]))
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(type(df.iloc[0:0]))
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```